# How to detect the specified part in a MP3 file?

Tags: mp3

I have more than 600 MP3 files, I just want to listen a part of each MP3 file. I know some MP3 cutter tools can do this job manually. Repeating the similar job more than 600+ times via MP3 cutter tool, that must be a very very boring and hard thing. So I need to write a program to finish this job automatically.

The specified part in each MP3 file have the almost same start/end part (5~8 seconds), if I can write a program to detect the start point and the end point, my question is nearly to be resolved.

PS: 
1) All the MP3 files are English learning podcast.
2) C or JAVA solution is prefered

Thanks

---

I find the specified part time was already listed in MP3 metadata, so my problem is resolved:

1) Read MP3 metadata, get the start time and end time, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21746702/3367812

2) cut MP3 file, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10056024/3367812

Comment: I would suggest that this question is better posted at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ as your looking for a software solution to your problem. This site is for programming related issues (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you very much! But software solution can't solve my problem, because the start time and the end time of each mp3 file is different. I have to write some codes to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked in several places.

You can follow this answer, which shows how to cut a wave file, to come up with your own program.

[cutting a wave file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462754/cutting-a-wave-file)

Comment: I think my wrong title mislead you. "cutting a wave file" is useful to me, but it's not enough. My difficulty is how to detect the cut part automatically. I will modify my tile.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. But you haven't mentioned how this specific part differs from the rest of the file.